# NVD3 - Pie Chart - Disable Hover and Where to Find Options

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to display a donut pie chart - one of these:

[image]

I have a few questions - been looking around on the D3 and NVD3 pages however can't find any answers:

1. How do i disable on hover showing the label and avoid the size increasing - as shown in the screenshot
2. Regarding adjusting the width - the chart itself doesnt seem to fit into the div, is there some width setting? I've used the chart option `width` directly however that seems to effect the containing box of the chart rather than teh chart itself
3. Going forward - where can i find a complete list of options available - i really can't find the one list?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you initiate the pie Chart use this attribute `.growOnHover(false)`. This is a property exact like the x,y,showLegend,showLabels and so on.